# Haskell class with instance of polymorph data definition

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism

I have a question regarding class definition with polymorphic data types. Lets say the defined datatype is:

```
data BTree a = BLeaf a | BNode a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving(Show)
```

Lets say I want to retrieve the value of the root of the tree, but within an instance of a class called Tree:

```
class Tree a where
             getRoot:: a -> (?)  --<- Type of Leave value as return type
```

and an instance:

```
instance Tree (BTree a) where
                        getRoot BLeaf a = a
                        getRoot BNode a _ _ = a
```

I can't figure out the type of the function (see questionmark), since its not a and the class doesn't know the parameter of the instance.

Comment: I think you'd have to leave it as a universal. (eg: getRoot :: a -> b, or more explicitly, getRoot :: forall b. a -> b).
Unless you know that the data type itself takes a typevariable, you can't really know the internal type. So you don't really have a choice but to just make "b" universally quantified.

Comment: Independent of answering this question, it is worth pushing back a bit. Why do you want a type class at all? I suspect you are bringing another language's idioms with you as you learn a new language. If you try to continue that way, you will be fighting the language the whole way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the type variable in the `class Tree` declaration refer to a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, and then you can refer to the type of the values of the tree in the type signature of `getRoot`.

```
class Tree t where
    getRoot :: t a -> a

instance Tree BTree where
    getRoot (BLeaf a)     = a
    getRoot (BNode a _ _) = a
```

Another, slightly more complex solution that allows the tree structure to be of kind `*` would be to use a [multi-parameter type class](https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class) along with [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Tree t a | t -> a where
    getRoot :: t -> a

instance Tree (BTree a) a where
    getRoot (BLeaf a)     = a
    getRoot (BNode a _ _) = a
```

Or you could use a [type family](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_families).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Tree t where
    type Value t
    getRoot :: t -> Value t

instance Tree (BTree a) where
    type Value (BTree a) = a
    getRoot (BLeaf a)     = a
    getRoot (BNode a _ _) = a
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, keep in mind that your `BTree` is a type with kind `* -> *`, which basically means it needs another type as argument to be created - your `a`. Because of that, having the type variable of your class called `a` as well can lead to confusion. Let's exchange that for `outer` to put it more clearly.

You'd then have:

```
class Tree outer where
    getRoot :: ???
```

On to the quest of finding that function's type. Knowing that the tree-type needs another type, we know `getRoot` must be passed something like `BTree Int`, which would be `outer inner` in variables. You want the function to return something which has that inner type, so your class would be:

```
class Tree outer where
    getRoot :: outer inner -> inner
```

Now that makes sense! You pass a tree to that function, and it presents you something with that inner type.

You'd then implement your instance as before:

```
instance Tree (BTree a) where
    getRoot (BLeaf x)     = x
    getRoot (BNode x _ _) = x
```